# requirejs optimizer - how to optimize css in dependencies

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

my module is like,

```
define(["angular","underscore","jquery","some/other/custom/module",   
"css!dropzone-css/dropzone.css"]
```

Using grunt task `grunt-requirejs`, How do I even specify css in `requirejs.compile.options.paths`?

Is there an other way ?
I can't modify define of the original module. That's external.

Thanks.